Is every compact analytic subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ finite?
"Let $\mathbb{C}^n$ be adopted with the Euclidean topology and $A$ be and analytic subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ (which means that for any $z\in \mathbb{C}^n$ there are an open neighborhood of $z$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and holomorphic functions $f_1,...,f_k:U\to\mathbb{C}$ s.t. $A\cap U = \{f_1=...=f_k=0\}$). If $A$ is compact then A is finite."
The result is true. I found the result in "Klaus, From holomorphic functins to complex manifolds (pg. 143)". However is there any elementary way to prove this theorem? (possibly assuming Hartogs thm, maximal principle for holomorphic function, elementary(?) theorems)
Originally I was trying to prove "if $g:\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}^n$ is  holomorphic and has no zeros on $S^{2n-1}$, then g has only finitely many zeros in $B^{2n}$ (this is problem1 of Appendix B in Singular Points of Complex Hypersurfaces by Milnor (pg.115))", and ended up with this question. An elementary proof for the original problem would also be of great help to me :)

Do you know how to prove this if $n=2$?

First, I think your definition is wrong. Aren’t the holomorphic functions assumed to be defined only on $U$? Second, do you know how to prove the claim when $A$ is a complex submanifold?

I know how to prove this for $n=1$ (by using the fact that every nontrival holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ does not accumulated zero. I don't know how to prove this for $n = 2$. But I guess that the prove would be same for  $2\leq n$.

@TedShifrin Opps. My mistake. You are right.

If you just want a reference, see Proposition on page 235 of
Łojasiewicz, Stanisław, Introduction to complex analytic geometry. Transl. from the Polish by Maciej Klimek, Basel etc.: Birkhäuser Veralg. xiv, 523 p. (1991). ZBL0747.32001.
But he proves this as a consequence of a much more general result that analytic functions on analytic subsets of complex manifolds are either locally constant or open (the "maximum principle").
Here is how one proves finiteness in $\mathbb C^n$. Let $A\subset V=\mathbb C^n$ be your compact analytic subset. Let $f$ be one of the coordinate functions on $V$. Then $f(A)$ is an analytic subset of $\mathbb C$: This is a consequence of Remmert's proper mapping  theorem, which is by no means an easy result (image of an analytic variety under a proper holomorphic map to another variety is an analytic subvariety of the target space). Here compactness of $A$ is used to ensure properness of $f|A$. Remmert's theorem you can find in Chirka's book as well.
Now, you use what you already know about analytic subsets of $\mathbb C$ and conclude that $f(A)$ is finite. Since this holds for all coordinate functions, it follows that $A$ is finite.
